# asp.net mvc 4 c# plus mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, webserver, shared-hosting

I would like to know if i use my web app in production in shared hosting, will be there a problem to use mongodb driver c# (driver is embedded in the project or need host support for that)?

Because I'm planning to use dedicated mongodb server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# driver is just a set of DLLs, so you're fine.

The only thing to check is that the shared host will allow traffic over whatever MongoDB port (it uses 27017 by default, although you can change that).

Comment: So you are saying that .dll files are included in the project and when i upload my web app .dll (mongodb) drivers will be with my project right?

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov yes, right.  You will just need to deploy the web app as normal, including your project DLL and the MongoDB driver DLLs.